# What should be my entry point if my MacOS app has no UI?

Tags: swift, macos, launch-daemon

i have a macos app that has no UI, its a Launch Daemon, and since this is my first app i wanted to check if im doing things right.
Is it ok to start running my code in the `AppDelegate` method `applicationDidFinishLaunching` or should i make another file my entry point. I read somewhere that im supposed to make a main.swift file but i havent found information about that.

Comment: It depends on the design of the app. Does it need a run loop or is a command line interface sufficient?

Comment: It is a Daemon that is supposed to run 24/7. The main functionality of the app is that is has a timer that makes a request to an api every couple of minutes

Comment: You can use both a faceless **app** and a command line interface (CLI) on the current run loop. I recommend the former. You have to specify the LSUIElement key in Info.plist.

Comment: Yeah i have set that in the plist. I was just asking wether it was correct to use AppDelegate as my entry point given that my app has no ui, no viewcontroller, etc

Comment: Yes, you can use `AppDelegate` as the entry point.